# How to add stock filter in stiemap.xml in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2.3, products, out-of-stock, stock-status, sitemaps

I want to exclude out of stock products from the sitemap.xml. I want to add stock filter like status or visibility filter in the product collection:

```
public function getCollection($storeId)
    {
        $products = [];

        /* @var $store Store */
        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId);
        if (!$store) {
            return false;
        }

        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        $urlRewriteMetaDataCondition = '';
        if (!$this->isCategoryProductURLsConfig($storeId)) {
            $urlRewriteMetaDataCondition = ' AND url_rewrite.metadata IS NULL';
        }

        $this->_select = $connection->select()->from(
            ['e' => $this->getMainTable()],
            [$this->getIdFieldName(), $this->_productResource->getLinkField(), 'updated_at']
        )->joinInner(
            ['w' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_website')],
            'e.entity_id = w.product_id',
            []
        )->joinLeft(
            ['url_rewrite' => $this->getTable('url_rewrite')],
            'e.entity_id = url_rewrite.entity_id AND url_rewrite.is_autogenerated = 1'
            . $urlRewriteMetaDataCondition
            . $connection->quoteInto(' AND url_rewrite.store_id = ?', $store->getId())
            . $connection->quoteInto(' AND url_rewrite.entity_type = ?', ProductUrlRewriteGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE),
            ['url' => 'request_path']
        )->where(
            'w.website_id = ?',
            $store->getWebsiteId()
        );
// echo $this->_select;
        // var_dump($this->_productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds()); die('hii');
        $this->_addFilter($store->getId(), 'visibility', $this->_productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds(), 'in');
        $this->_addFilter($store->getId(), 'status', $this->_productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds(), 'in');

        // Join product images required attributes
        $imageIncludePolicy = $this->_sitemapData->getProductImageIncludePolicy($store->getId());
        if (\Magento\Sitemap\Model\Source\Product\Image\IncludeImage::INCLUDE_NONE != $imageIncludePolicy) {
            $this->_joinAttribute($store->getId(), 'name', 'name');
            if (\Magento\Sitemap\Model\Source\Product\Image\IncludeImage::INCLUDE_ALL == $imageIncludePolicy) {
                $this->_joinAttribute($store->getId(), 'thumbnail', 'thumbnail');
            } elseif (\Magento\Sitemap\Model\Source\Product\Image\IncludeImage::INCLUDE_BASE == $imageIncludePolicy) {
                $this->_joinAttribute($store->getId(), 'image', 'image');
            }
        }

        $query = $connection->query($this->prepareSelectStatement($this->_select));
        while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
            $product = $this->_prepareProduct($row, $store->getId());
            $products[$product->getId()] = $product;
        }

        return $products;
    }
```

I have tried this code:

```
$this->_addFilter($store->getId(), 'quantity_and_stock_status',1, 'in');
```

But it is not working. Can anyone suggest how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have done a stock filter in a sitemap.xml

**Replace this code:**

```
$this->_select = $connection->select()->from(
            ['e' => $this->getMainTable()],
            [$this->getIdFieldName(), $this->_productResource->getLinkField(), 'updated_at']
        )->joinInner(
            ['w' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_website')],
            'e.entity_id = w.product_id',
            []
        )->joinLeft(
            ['url_rewrite' => $this->getTable('url_rewrite')],
            'e.entity_id = url_rewrite.entity_id AND url_rewrite.is_autogenerated = 1'
            . $urlRewriteMetaDataCondition
            . $connection->quoteInto(' AND url_rewrite.store_id = ?', $store->getId())
            . $connection->quoteInto(' AND url_rewrite.entity_type = ?', ProductUrlRewriteGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE),
            ['url' => 'request_path']
        )->where(
            'w.website_id = ?',
            $store->getWebsiteId()
        );
```

**with this code:**

```
$this->_select = $connection->select()->from(
            ['e' => $this->getMainTable()],
            [$this->getIdFieldName(), $this->_productResource->getLinkField(), 'updated_at']
        )->joinInner(
            ['w' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_website')],
            'e.entity_id = w.product_id',
            []
        )->joinLeft(
            ['url_rewrite' => $this->getTable('url_rewrite')],
            'e.entity_id = url_rewrite.entity_id AND url_rewrite.is_autogenerated = 1'
            . $urlRewriteMetaDataCondition
            . $connection->quoteInto(' AND url_rewrite.store_id = ?', $store->getId())
            . $connection->quoteInto(' AND url_rewrite.entity_type = ?', ProductUrlRewriteGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE),
            ['url' => 'request_path']
        )->joinLeft(
            ['ciss' => $this->getTable('cataloginventory_stock_status')],
            'e.entity_id = ciss.product_id'
        )->where(
            'w.website_id = ?',
            $store->getWebsiteId()
        )->where(
            'ciss.stock_status = 1'
        );
```